# What's a good way to refresh a page with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, header, meta

This seems like it should be simple enough but I'm having a little trouble.

I have an index page which is both the login page and the main content page, depending on whether or not a session variable is set.

I've tried using JavaScript which is echoed from PHP to handle redirects but it looked sloppy and takes a little bit of time, so I switched to using header("location: abc.php"). The problem with using that for the index page is that it doesn't work after output is sent. I've also tried using a meta tag to refresh the page but that doesn't work in all browsers.

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use output buffering to send headers after content has been generated.

Comment: The answer is simple and to me it is obvious: don't send any output before deciding if you need to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of them. However, `header("location: abc.php")` will not work after sending response! The work around is simple. Use output buffering.

```
<?php
ob_start()

//here goes many lines of your wonderful php code blocks

//now send the header based on your logic
header("location: abc.php")

ob_end_flush()
```

Please check the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for more info

Update:
You can consider the suggestion of @zerkms. If you really need to silently redirect to other page, do that before sending any outputs using `header()` function. However, if you want to show that you are redirecting him/her, you can use javascript as you were using! For the latter, you can also use [Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

`ob_start()` will be helpful for this. Because, you will probably show many things on the page and then tell that he/she will be redirected momentarily. The above example will redirect user to example.com in 5 seconds.

Comment: The workaround you proposed makes no sense. If you want to redirect user - there is no reason to output anything. Yes, it's that simple.

Comment: Your point is valid! However, please check the question where he said it does not work after sending output is sent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear. I gave examples of how I had redirected on other pages, maybe that was irrelevant. I'm not trying to redirect, I'm trying to refresh the same page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

//all of the php code goes here

header("location: samepage.php")

?>
```

make sure your all code of php is at top level of your browser and not using any echo command - else you will end up showing something that is echo at the top of the page - instead of using echo command use variable that are more reliable then use variable in html body where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
  header("Location: mainpage.php");
  exit();
}

// Display login form
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <!--The page will refresh every 5 seconds.-->   
 <body onload="timedRefresh(5000)">
```

Comment: @HiggsBoson this what you are looking for?

Comment: this is basically what i'm using now, it's slow though because the whole page loads into the browser before the js is executed :/